# Finding strings and operating with cells in big size excel page

Tags: string, excel, vba, cell

I am handling a big data Excel page (lets call it page **P.Source**) and I need to use pointers to manage the strings in a very specific way.

I need to look all the ocurrences of a string in a column in the **whole rangue A:A** and for each ocurrence detection do the following:

```
"String detected in Ax cell" (x is the number of cell)
-> Set the pointer to A(x-3) cell and copy this value to other page (P.Other) into the cell A1.
-> Set the pointer to B(x-3) cell and copy this value to other page (P.Other) into the cell B1.
```

In triying to figure out this by using generic functions as .Find through a loop but Im having problems with it.

I hope somebody can guide me with some function or operative method for approach a solution since I'm not very familiar with VBA.

Thank you very much.

---

**EDIT:**

Completing the coment of

> Gary's Student

What I want to to do is the following:

Taking this as P. Source:

[image]

The result I want is the following in P. Other (taking "happiness" as my string):

[image]

That is, copy the text of A (2-1), B (2-1) and D (2-1) because it has detected the first happines in A2 and then copy the text of A (7-1) , B (7-1) and D (7-1) because it has detected the second happines in A7.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Say we have data like:

[image]

and the string we want is "happiness".  Running this macro:

```
Sub Macro2()
    Range("A:B").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$B").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "=*happiness*", Operator:=xlAnd
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("P.Other").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

will produce this:

[image]

In sheet *P.Other*

Please note:

**This came from the macro recorder.**

Comment: This looks interesting. With a small modification I think it might be enough for my purpose.

Could you help me with the modification of which I speak? Please read my edit in the OP!

Answer (score -1):

You could try the Like operator
(Short example)

```
For Each c In [A:A] If c.Font.Name Like "Sample*" Then c.Font.Name = "Times New Roman" End If Next
```

[Like Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/swf8kaxw.aspx).